# Saving a stack of images in TIFF format

Tags: c++, image, save, tiff, libtiff

I am trying to save a stack of the same image in a TIFF format but when I open the image with such application as ImageJ I can only view the first image; the 2nd and the third image cannot be displayed. I believe the TIFF image contains the image data for the 2nd and 3rd image as the size is 3 times larger than a single tiff image.

I have used the following code but has no luck.

```
int NPAGES = 3;
for (int page = 0; page < NPAGES; page++) {
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, frame->Width);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, frame->Height);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 16);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);

    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, PHOTOMETRIC_MINISBLACK);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE, (1 << frame->BitDepth) - 1);

    /// added 
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_SUBFILETYPE, FILETYPE_PAGE);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PAGENUMBER, page, NPAGES);
    TIFFWriteRawStrip(out, 0, (void*)image, frame->RawImageData->Length * 2);
}
```

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: You should try to post a [functional example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because there could be an error somewhere else (such as the initialization of `image`).  Have you tried opening the file in a viewer other than ImageJ? I've found that very few image viewer implement the entire capability of a given image standard.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`TIFFWriteDirectory`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tiffwritedirectory) closes off a directory (page) and starts a new one. Call this function at the end of the loop, so each iteration starts with a fresh directory. You don’t need to explicitly set the page number.

```
for (int page = 0; page < NPAGES; page++) {
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, frame->Width);
    TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, frame->Height);
    //...
    TIFFWriteDirectory(out);
}
```